# Why global ExecutionContext is not a default parameter in future block?

Tags: scala, future

That's really annoying when you write some highly concurrent code with Futures or Actors response and you have manually import `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`. Tried to find some good explanation why it's not made as a default parameter, like it is [done](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/concurrent/src/main/scala/scalaz/concurrent/Future.scala#L338) with `Strategy` in `Scalaz Concurrent`. That would be very helpful, not to insert/remove all those imports in the code. Or am i missing some logic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The general trend seems to be to require the user to explicitly import things like implicits, extra operators or DSLs. I think this is a good thing since it makes things less "magic" and more understandable.

But nothing stops you from defining a package-wide implicit value for your code. Note that if the implicit ExecutionContext was always imported by default, you wouldn't be able to do this.

In the package object:

```
package object myawsomeconcurrencylibrary {
  implicit def defaultExecutionContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
}
```

In any class in the same package:

```
package myawsomeconcurrencylibrary

object Bla {
  future { ... } // implicit from package object is used unless you explicitly provide your own
}
```